# cuda opencv undefined reference to `nppiConvert_16u8u_C4R`

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda, npp

I am trying to run a opencv based simple rgb to gray scale script and run it through cuda. The header for the C++ script that does the computation links the following api from `opencv`:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>                                                
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>                                          
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
```

I am trying to compile it using the following `makefile` logic:

```
OPENCV_LIBPATH=-L/apps/gcc/4.7.2/opencv/2.4.8/lib 
OPENCV_LIBPATH += -l/opt/cuda/5.5/lib64

OPENCV_INCLUDEPATH=/apps/gcc/4.7.2/opencv/2.4.8/include                         
OPENCV_LIBS=-lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lnppi -lz                   
CUDA_INCLUDEPATH=/opt/cuda/5.5/include                                          

NVCC_OPTS=-O3 -arch=sm_20 -Xcompiler -Wall -Xcompiler -Wextra -m64              

GCC_OPTS=-O3 -Wall -Wextra -m64                                                 

main: rgbtogrey.o rgb_to_grey.o Makefile                                     
    $(NVCC) -o main.out rgbtogrey.o rgb_to_grey.o -I$(OPENCV_INCLUDEPATH) $(OPENCV_LIBPATH) $(OPENCV_LIBS)

rgbtogrey.o: rgbtogrey.cpp timer.h utils.h                                      
    g++ -c rgbtogrey.cpp $(GCC_OPTS) -I $(CUDA_INCLUDEPATH) -I $(OPENCV_INCLUDEPATH)

rgb_to_grey.o: rgb_to_grey.cu utils.h                                           
    nvcc -c rgb_to_grey.cu $(NVCC_OPTS)                                         

clean:                                                                          
    rm -f *.o hw
```

I tried a number of other solutions such as those outlined in 
[Compiling a basic opencv cuda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842197/compiling-a-basic-opencv-cuda-program-on-linux)  and [Linking Cuda in C++ issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17151941/linking-cuda-in-c-issue).

Current Error:

```
/apps/gcc/4.7.2/opencv/2.4.8/lib/libopencv_highgui.a(grfmt_exr.cpp.o): In function `cv::ExrDecoder::ExrDecoder()':
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoderC2Ev+0x9d): undefined reference to `Imf::Chromaticities::Chromaticities(Imath::Vec2<float> const&, Imath::Vec2<float> const&, Imath::Vec2<float> const&, Imath::Vec2<float> const&)'
```

I am pretty new to this as such am not sure where to look for to solve this error.

EDIT: 
1. Following the comment I added the `lnppi` option to the main after adding the LIB path (see makefile portion updated)

Error now:

```
/apps/gcc/4.7.2/opencv/2.4.8/lib/libopencv_core.a(persistence.cpp.o): In function `icvGets(CvFileStorage
persistence.cpp:(.text._ZL7icvGetsP13CvFileStoragePci+0x127): undefined reference to `gzgets'
```

2. added link to zlib via `lz`

Comment: In order to access NPPI functions, you will need to link to the NPPI library. I don't see that in your makefile.

Comment: And for `gzgets` you need to link zlib

Comment: thanks added lz. but stilll getting error

Comment: Seems like you are linking to static version of opencv. In that case, you would have to link all dependencies of opencv as well e.g. `libIlmImf, libjpeg, libpng, libtiff, zlib` etc.

Comment: thanks... linking these solved the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the attached libraries under the OpenCV's `OPENCV_PATH/3rdparty/lib` folder by `-libIlmImf -llibjpeg -llibjasper -llibpng -lzlib`.
Also take care to the order in which libraries are linked, because any static library must be linked in the appropriate order otherwise unresolved references will appear with GNU ld:

> If any [static] **library A** depends on symbols defined in **library B**,
>   then **library A** should appear first in the list supplied to the linker.

See [linker order - GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/linker-order-gcc) for more information.

Comment: thanks!.. i solved it by adding the libs acc to @sgarizvi 's comments. Thanks for the answer. can you add the libIlmImf to your ans . I want to accept this for any other person stumbling onto this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my case, I tried to use OpenCV on android. So I put `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += libjpeg libpng libtiff libjasper IlmImf opencv_highgui opencv_core opencv_improc`. Then I got a long list of compiler errors. After the highgui moved before the 3rd party libraries, (`LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += opencv_highgui libjpeg libpng libtiff libjasper IlmImf opencv_core opencv_improc`) the compiler errors are gone.